# Java - Returning the smallest element of the given non-empty array

Tags: java

I am studying Java and trying to find the bug in my code.

It is suppose to return the smallest element of the given non-empty array.

It works with B = [-3, 4, -2, -2]

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
class Test {
    int test(int[] B, int[] C) {
        int ans = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < B.length; i++) {
            if (ans > B[I]) {
                ans = B[i];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend stepping through your code when `B` only contains positive integers, or if `B` only contains a single element.

Comment: And remember that array indexes start at zero.

Comment: Just set ans to `B[0]` and not `0` and ensure you're indexing by `i` and not 'I`.  And please don;t worry about using streams as you won;t learn the basics of how stuff works.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your bug is because you're setting the ans variable to 0, instead of setting it to the maximum integer value ( MAX_VALUE )  as indicated by most solutions above :

```
int test(int[] B) {
    int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        if (ans > B[I]) {
            ans = B[i];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Your solution will only work if the given array consists of at-least 1 non-positive element. Once you have an Array with all positive elements, you solution will always return a 0 because no element in an array will ever be less than your initially assumed minimum which is zero in your case.

**Alternatively to using streams :** you can sort the Array first and get the first element, assuming it will be sorted in ascending order:

```
int test(int[] B) {
    Arrays.sort(B); // Sorts the array in ascending order
    return B[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you check the use of streams in your solution?

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci, I don't think I understand your question. Check as in, you mean can I provide a solution using streams ?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are 0th based index in Java so start your for loop with i=0

```
class Test {
    int test(int[] B) {
        int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
            if (ans > B[i]) {
                ans = B[i];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code: One is that you set `ans` to 0 in initialization. The second is that you start from index 1 rather than index 0, so you may be missing values that way.

Happily, these two problems can be solved with one solution:

```
class Test {
    int test(int[] B) {
        int ans = B[0]; // use the first element of the array as the start value for ans. 
        //Doing that, you don't need to change your loop
        for (int i = 1; i < B.length; i++) {
            if (ans > B[i]) {
                ans = B[i];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is the solution. I guess it works, but if code-reviewing such code my feedback to the developer would be that it’s less obvious to other developers what you’re trying to do with no appreciable gain (the comment helps). It also has the limitation that it will not work on empty arrays, instead causing a runtime error (crash). That IMO would be an even bigger bug.

Comment: @AlvinThompson " It also has the limitation that it will not work on empty arrays, instead causing a runtime error (crash). That IMO would be an even bigger bug." Getting the minimum from an empty array makes no sense (what int value do you think it should return?) Instead, it should throw an Exception - personally, I think the IndexOutOfBoundsException covers this pretty well.

Comment: I have at least SEVEN issues with that logic. First, if it's incorrect to pass an empty array to this function, then the real bug occurred *elsewhere*. It's in the code that supplied this function; not in here. Throwing an exception that doesn't describe that fact is misleading and will simply waste the developer assigned to fix the problem’s time. Developers aren’t cheap so time is money.

Comment: Second, an IndexOutOfBoundsException is misleading because it has nothing to do with the actual problem and is rather a byproduct of it. If you absolutely insist on using a RuntimeException (you shouldn’t), it should be an IllegalArgumentException, preferably with a message that describes that the array was empty. Again, you’re just wasting the developer’s time—especially if a stack trace isn’t immediately available.

Comment: Third, if it *is* so incorrect to pass an empty function that you think the caller should deal with it, you should throw a documented CHECKED exception and force the caller to deal with it in that fashion. That’s why exceptions like ParseException are checked even though you could argue it is a type of IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Fourth and probably most important, you’re writing less clear, less robust code for NO GAIN WHATSOEVER! No one cares how clever you THINK you are by altering only one line of code instead of two.  And if your code has additional arbitrary restrictions on it for no gain, you’re actually sending the message that you’re not as clever as you think.

Comment: Fifth, you’re assuming that you know better than the calling code what that code is trying to do and how an exception should be handled. Since unchecked exceptions should not be caught, you’re saying that there’s no conceivable circumstance where handling an empty set might be useful. Such absolutes are usually wrong. You’re violating a cardinal rule: NEVER make unnecessary assumptions about how this method is going to be used—and certainly not undocumented ones.

Comment: Sixth and also very important these days, a version of this method that can handle an empty set actually offers potentially far better performance because it can more easily be horizontally scaled. What if the list of ints contained a billion elements? It would be more efficient to break it up into subsets, assign each to a different thread/node, collect the results into a new set and call the method again. There already is plenty of code that does that, but that code generally doesn’t guarantee there won’t be empty sets.

Comment: Finally, since you are changing someone else’s code because of problems, the diff should be clear what was the issue and why. The diff from your changes makes that less clear and the developers reviewing the diff has to spend more time figuring out if it’s correct. Again, developers are expensive so don’t waste their time. Again, no one cares how clever you think you are, and they *definitely* don’t care when you wasted their time.

Comment: BTW, for some reason I can't tag you in a reply.

Comment: @AlvinThompson ...wow

Comment: Wow, yes. I've been a writing software  for 25 years and there's no bigger waste of time than a developer trying to prove how "clever" he is. Write code that works and is maintainable. That's all I ask.

Answer (score 1):

**Test Question**

I was searching a solution to my problem on the Internet, and I saw your question. I think the problem here is changing only one line, at least my question was like that.

I solved it in **Python** but I will share also the **Java** Solution.

This is the starting code given in **Python**,

```
def solution(A):
    ans = 0
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if A[i] < ans:
            ans = A[i]
    return ans
```

And this is my solution to it with only one line change!

```
def solution(A):
    ans = A[0]
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if A[i] < ans:
            ans = A[i]
    return ans
```

If we think the same think for the **Java** code which you shared (I corrected some part of your codes already),

```
class Test {
    int test(int[] B) {
        int ans = B[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < B.length; i++) {
            if (ans > B[i]) {
                ans = B[i];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

I know this is a specific solution for the question and there are some rules like array cannot be empty.. But I hope it will helps the others. Other solutions are also correct. The only difference that I made it only one line change.

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that your above code will fail

```
Input: B = [1,2,3,4,5]
Expected Output: 1
Your Output: 0
```

The root cause is that the initial value of `ans` is 0. Set it to `1001` (or any other int value that is greater than the maximum value of the range) **AND** traverse from the first element of the array instead of the second one would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are not considering the first element of the array. Either set `ans` to that or start looping from index `0` and set ans to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which will also work for an empty array).

```
int test(int[] B) {
    int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        if (ans > B[I]) {
            ans = B[i];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

For a shorter solution, you can use `IntStream.min`.

```
int test(int[] B){
    return Arrays.stream(B).min().orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    //return minimum or Integer.MAX_VALUE if the array is empty
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course there is a bug, even more than one. There will always be bugs if you try to do things in a complex way, this is a perfect example of accidental complexity. What you are trying to do here is not obvious from this code at first glance, I have to look into it, analyze it and think on it for a while.

Look at something like this:

```java
int findMinimum(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).min().getAsInt();
}
```

1. I can immediately see what this method does - the `min()` just jumps at me
2. if it compiles then there is a big chance it works, hard to make a mistake here
3. I can easy handle the case of array being empty - I added `getAsInt` at the end, but without it I would have an `OptionalInt` - it's just a good practice to handle such edge cases, trying to find something in an empty array is not that uncommon
4. easy to handle similiar cases - finding `maximum` (`max()`) or `average` (`average()`) and many more

Note: this is a 'good practice' answer, since there already are answers that answer the problem here - maybe someone will benefit